# How should I set the turbulent prandtl number in a turbulent compressible flow simulation?

Tags: cfd, turbulence

I'm working on simulating compressible fluid flow over a flat plate with turbulence.  The energy equation for compressible flow with turbulence requires modeling a turbulent heat flux of the form

$$q_T=\frac{\mu_T c_p}{Pr_T}\frac{\partial T}{\partial x_j}$$

where $\mu_T, c_p,Pr_T$ are the turbulent viscosity, specific heat (constant pressure) and turbulent Prandtl number.  Clearly, all three of these paramters vary throughout the domain and require a model to determine their values as a function of the flow variables (density $\rho$, velocity $u$, pressure $p$, and temperature $T$.  The turbulent viscosity is estimated using the variables of the specifically chosen turbulence model.  The specific heat $c_p$ is a function of temperature, and can be estimated by interpolating over the most recent temperature values.

However, I have no idea how to estimate the turbulent Prandtl number as a function of the temperature, velocity, density, or pressure.  The only relevant discussion I've found on this issue is in Wilcox (2006)'s *Turbulence Modeling for CFD* (chapter 5, section 5.4.2, pg 250), where it states

> A constant value for $Pr_T$ is often used and this is usually satisfactory for shock-free flows up to low supersonic speeds, provided the heat transfer rate is not too high.  The most common values assumed for $Pr_T$ are 0.89 or 0.90, in the case of a boundary layer.  Heat transfer predictions can usually be improved somewhat by letting $Pr_T$ vary through the boundary layer.  Near the edge of a boundary layer and throughout a free shear layer, a value of the order of 0.5 is more appropriate for $Pr_T$.

While modeling $Pr_T$ as a constant is OK for some cases, I want to know if there is a standard model to prescribe its value as a function of the flow variables $T,u,\rho,$ and $p$.  Preferably, this model should ascribe values near 0.9 within the boundary layer and 0.5 throughout a free shear layer, as described by Wilcox.  How should I prescribe the turbulent Prandtl number throughout the domain as a function of the flow variables?